# Is there a way to use only `/login/oauth2/code/:registration_id` in spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

First of all, I don't want to provide a web view for social login on my mobile

The social login method for spring security is to call `/oauth2/authorization/:registration_id` and then `/login/oauth2/code/:registration_id`.

However, if you are using SDK on mobile, I don't need `/oauth2/authorization/:registration_id`, only need `/login/oauth2/code/:registration_id`.
However, it seems that only `/login/oauth2/code/:registration_id` is not provided.

Is there a way to use only `/login/oauth2/code/:registration_id` in spring security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the side effect, but I found a way to work.

```
package com.example.demo.config.security;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.AuthorizationRequestRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationRequest;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2ParameterNames;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.UrlUtils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository implements AuthorizationRequestRepository<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest> {
    private static final char PATH_DELIMITER = '/';
    private final InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest loadAuthorizationRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ClientRegistration clientRegistration = resolveRegistration(request);
        if (clientRegistration == null) {
            return null;
        }

        String redirectUriAction = getAction(request, "login");
        String redirectUriStr = expandRedirectUri(request, clientRegistration, redirectUriAction);

        return OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.authorizationCode()
                .attributes((attrs) -> attrs.put(OAuth2ParameterNames.REGISTRATION_ID, clientRegistration.getRegistrationId()))
                .clientId(clientRegistration.getClientId())
                .redirectUri(redirectUriStr)
                .authorizationUri(clientRegistration.getProviderDetails().getAuthorizationUri())
                .state(request.getParameter("state"))
                .scopes(clientRegistration.getScopes())
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void saveAuthorizationRequest(OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest removeAuthorizationRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return loadAuthorizationRequest(request);
    }

    private ClientRegistration resolveRegistration(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(clientRegistrationRepository.spliterator(), false)
                .filter(registration -> {
                    return Optional
                            .ofNullable(UriComponentsBuilder
                                    .fromHttpUrl(registration.getRedirectUri())
                                    .build().getPath())
                            .orElse("")
                            .equals(request.getRequestURI());
                })
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }

    private String getAction(HttpServletRequest request, String defaultAction) {
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        if (action == null) {
            return defaultAction;
        }
        return action;
    }

    private static String expandRedirectUri(HttpServletRequest request, ClientRegistration clientRegistration,
                                            String action) {
        Map<String, String> uriVariables = new HashMap<>();
        uriVariables.put("registrationId", clientRegistration.getRegistrationId());
        // @formatter:off
        UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(UrlUtils.buildFullRequestUrl(request))
                .replacePath(request.getContextPath())
                .replaceQuery(null)
                .fragment(null)
                .build();
        // @formatter:on
        String scheme = uriComponents.getScheme();
        uriVariables.put("baseScheme", (scheme != null) ? scheme : "");
        String host = uriComponents.getHost();
        uriVariables.put("baseHost", (host != null) ? host : "");
        // following logic is based on HierarchicalUriComponents#toUriString()
        int port = uriComponents.getPort();
        uriVariables.put("basePort", (port == -1) ? "" : ":" + port);
        String path = uriComponents.getPath();
        if (StringUtils.hasLength(path)) {
            if (path.charAt(0) != PATH_DELIMITER) {
                path = PATH_DELIMITER + path;
            }
        }
        uriVariables.put("basePath", (path != null) ? path : "");
        uriVariables.put("baseUrl", uriComponents.toUriString());
        uriVariables.put("action", (action != null) ? action : "");
        return UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(clientRegistration.getRedirectUri()).buildAndExpand(uriVariables)
                .toUriString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mobile app is an OAuth2 **client**. It should handle authentication with the authorization-server and then add Authorization header with Bearer token to the request it send to secured resource-server(s).

For **authorization-server**, two options:

- use your "social" identity provider if it support OAuth2 but this is rarely possible, see below
- put an authorization-server in front of "social" identity provider(s). This can be useful in many cases (Keycloak for instance works for all below and is in my opinion a way more mature solution than Spring's authorization-server):

  - you have several identity sources (Google, Facebook, etc)
  - you need to add role management to your users (some users need to be identified as moderators or whatever elevated privileges)
  - you have non OAuth2 identity sources (database or corporate LDAP for instance)
  - several identity sources but some of it are not issuing OpenID JWT access-tokens

Last, the **resource-server** (REST API) which can completely ignore login flows (which should be handled by client). All it needs is an Authorization header with a bearer token and either a JWT decoder or an introspection endpoint. See [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-oauth2-resource-servers) for configuring such a resource-server.

I configure my resource-servers to return 401 (unauthorized) when Authorization header is invalid or missing, and not 302 (redirect to login):

- in my opinion, this is client responsibility to handle end-user login and also know which URIs require an Authorization (and from which issuer): if your app consumes resources from different providers (for instance Facebook plus Google Maps plus your own Spring services) it must know what access-token to associate with which request.
- you can end with cases where your resource-server is exposed to several clients with different issuers. In that case, do you really want to put some code in your resource-servers to figure out to which authorization-server redirect depending on the client ID?